# Getting the ApplicationUser object in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, findname, usermanager

I am writing a C# MVC5 internet application and am having some trouble getting the `ApplicationUser` object in a controller that I have created.

Here is my code:

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
ApplicationUser user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Result;
```

When I try to run this code, when a user is logged in, I am getting a null object for the `ApplicationUser` user.

Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FindByNameAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497543(v=vs.108).aspx) expects a username but you're passing the user id. Either pass the username...

```
ApplicationUser user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.GetUserName()).Result;
```

Or use the [`FindByIdAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497542(v=vs.108).aspx) method...

```
ApplicationUser user = userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Result;
```